Not Standard Input behavior?
I'm trying to automate something with a browser extension, and I'm facing a problem with an input.
The thing is, I can't set that specific input value to anything from the extension.      If I do it manually from the console it works.
Setting the value does not work.
Using events does not work.
.click and .focus do not work, the value I set appears in the ui but the .value property is still "" and after a few seconds it disappears.
I found a thread on reddit describing the same problem a year ago but it does not provide a solution.
Any idea of what else can I do?

are you saying that after updating the value .value = 'something'; then referencing the .value it gives you ""? that doesn't sound right

We'll need a [mcve] to help you with this. What does the site do with the input, what does your extension do?

@Bergi the input is just part of a form, I cannot find what is the website doing with the input to create that behavior, my extension only fills a couple of inputs with preloaded information, what I noticed, and I think it might be related is that input has a bunch of event listeners, for focus, for click, keydown,keyup, etc and it looks like it is just preventing some of this events to reach the input under some conditions

and I do not own the website and to even see the form you have to loging so I am not sure how I can create a minimal reproducible example because I have no idea what is even causing the issue in the first place

I found the issue, my problem was https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/releases/tag/4.0.6 onfocus event, for some reason while this listener is on the item I can't just change the value, the solution was simple but is weird an not intuitive
 input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
 input.value = newValue;
 input.focus();
 input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

